# ruby unless bug with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby, multiple-conditions

Common Code:

```
class ThingA end
class ThingB end
class ThingC end
```

In order to set up conditional checks for the above types, I used the basic "if !..." construct that produced the accurate results as expected.

Sample Code if ! ...:

```
obj = ThingA.new
puts 'yes it is a ThingC' if !obj.is_a?(ThingA) && !obj.is_a?(ThingB) # works ok
# stdout => nothing

obj = ThingB.new
puts 'yes it is a ThingC' if !obj.is_a?(ThingA) && !obj.is_a?(ThingB) # works ok
# stdout => nothing

obj = ThingC.new
puts 'yes it is a ThingC' if !obj.is_a?(ThingA) && !obj.is_a?(ThingB) # works ok
# stdout => yes it is a ThingC
```

Considering the fact that "unless" is a more descriptive alternative to the basic "if !..." construct, I implemented the above using "unless", instead.

Sample Code unless:

```
obj = ThingA.new
puts 'yes it is a ThingC' unless obj.is_a?(ThingA) && obj.is_a?(ThingB) # BUG
# stdout => yes it is a ThingC

obj = ThingB.new
puts 'yes it is a ThingC' unless obj.is_a?(ThingA) && obj.is_a?(ThingB) # BUG
# stdout => yes it is a ThingC

obj = ThingC.new
puts 'yes it is a ThingC' unless obj.is_a?(ThingA) && obj.is_a?(ThingB) # ???
# stdout => yes it is a ThingC
```

Evidently, the "unless" version fails to produce the identical accurate  results.

Based upon these simple and straight-forward results, would it be hard for anyone to conclude that "multiple conditions are not handled by unless accurately"?

Answer (score 22):

## Logic with unless

Boolean logic becomes hard to parse with `unless`. You can rewrite it with `if`:

- `unless a || b` is equivalent to `if !(a || b)`, which is equivalent to `if !a && !b`
- `unless a && b` is equivalent to `if !(a && b)`, which is equivalent to `if !a || !b`

## Your "Bug"

`obj.is_a?(ThingA) && obj.is_a?(ThingB)` must be `false` if `ThingA` and `ThingB` are independent classes.

It could only be `true` if one class was a subclass of the other. In this case, you would only need to check if `obj` is a Subclass instance :

`obj.is_a?(ThingA) && obj.is_a?(Object)` is true if and only if `obj` is a `ThingA` object, so you could just write :

`obj.is_a?(ThingA)`

## Alternatives

For your example, you should probably use `case` :

```
obj = ThingA.new

case obj
when ThingA
  puts "yes, it is a ThingA"
when ThingB
  puts "yes, it is a ThingB"
when ThingC
  puts "yes, it is a ThingC"
else
  puts "no, it is some other Object"
end
```

or

```
case obj
when ThingA, ThingB, ThingC
  puts "yes, it is a Thing A B or C"
else
  puts "no, it is some other Object"
end
```

or

```
puts "yes, it is a #{obj.class}"
```

They return :

```
yes, it is a ThingA
yes, it is a Thing A B or C
yes, it is a ThingA
```

Comment: Might be clearer if you started with "`unless expr` is equivalent to `if !(expr)`" and then move on to a compound `expr` and DeMorgan's Laws.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is with the logic and or or, when you negate a logical function the equivalent is the opossite and the precedence of operator: the logic functions before the modifier

> De Morgan's laws provide a way of distributing negation over
>   disjunction and conjunction :
>
> ```
> ¬ ( a ∨ b ) ≡ ( ¬ a ∧ ¬ b ),
> ```
>
> and
>       ¬ ( a ∧ b ) ≡ ( ¬ a ∨ ¬ b )

In your case,

> (not(a) and not(b)) then you negate it => not(a or b)
>
> and unless => not if

```
irb(main):001:0> class ThingA end
class ThingB end
class ThingC end
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> => nil
irb(main):003:0> => nil

irb(main):004:0> obj = ThingA.new
puts 'yes it is a ThingC' unless obj.is_a?(ThingA) || obj.is_a?(ThingB

obj = ThingB.new
puts 'yes it is a ThingC' unless obj.is_a?(ThingA) || obj.is_a?(ThingB) 

obj = ThingC.new
puts 'yes it is a ThingC' unless obj.is_a?(ThingA) || obj.is_a?(ThingB) 

<ThingA:0x000000025fc060>
    irb(main):005:0> => nil
<ThingB:0x00000002749d00>
    irb(main):009:0> => nil
<ThingC:0x000000027be420>
    irb(main):013:0> yes it is a ThingC
    => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned already that I wanted to set up a "Neither x AND Nor y" filter. I went for `if !obj.is_a?(ThingA) && !obj.is_a?(ThingB)`. Not only does it work but it also conveys the intention clearly "Neither ThingA AND Nor ThingB".

Now the question arises, why did I remove all the `!`s from this statement, replaced `if` with `unless` and expected the new version to produce identical results? The answer lies in how some/most of us were introduced to `unless` in the first place. Statements like "Ruby can also perform unless tests, which are the exact opposite of if tests..." and "Think of unless as being an alternative way of expressing “if not.”" (direct quotes from The Book of Ruby by Huw Collingbourne: pg87), basically led (more like misled) me to believe that `unless` can be used as an alternative to `if !` in any scenario. That is why I expected it to work here as well.

New Year's Resolution item 1: `unless` is strictly off-limits for anything involving more than one condition.

Anyone still held bent on solving the compound-conditional `if !` problems with `unless` could do so by enclosing the whole argument within `!()`. For example, the above could be solved as `unless !( !obj.is_a?(ThingA) && !obj.is_a?(ThingB) )`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any bug here. Output you have got is logical. Let me breakdown your code.

```
obj = ThingA.new
puts 'yes it is a ThingC' unless obj.is_a?(ThingA) && obj.is_a?(ThingB) # BUG
```

`obj.is_a?(ThingB)` is `false`. so `false && obj.is_a?(ThingB)` is `false`. `unless false` is `true`. So it prints.

```
obj = ThingB.new
puts 'yes it is a ThingC' unless obj.is_a?(ThingA) && obj.is_a?(ThingB)
```

`obj.is_a?(ThingA)` is false. `false && obj.is_a?(ThingB)` is `false`. `unless false` is `true`. So it prints.

```
obj = ThingC.new
puts 'yes it is a ThingC' unless obj.is_a?(ThingA) && obj.is_a?(ThingB)
```

`obj.is_a?(ThingA)` is `false`. `false && obj.is_a?(ThingB)` is `false`.`unless false` is `true`. So it prints.